# Understand Substitution used in Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

This is a solution I had come across for a general case.$$$$

We will use
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$$
$$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}$$
& we will first solve the general case
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}x^me^{-kx^n}\,dx$$
take $y=kn^x$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{n\cdot k^{\frac{m+1}{n}}}\int_0^{\infty}y^{\frac{m+1}{n}-1}e^{-y}\,dy$$
$$I=\frac{1}{n\cdot k^{\frac{m+1}{n}}}\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{n})$$

Could someone please explain how $y=kn^x$ transforms $$I=\int_0^{\infty}x^me^{-kx^n}\,dx$$ to $$\Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{n\cdot k^{\frac{m+1}{n}}}\int_0^{\infty}y^{\frac{m+1}{n}-1}e^{-y}\,dy$$
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=kx^n$ we get $dy=nkx^{n-1}dx$ and we transform the integral by substituting
$x=\left(\frac{y}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $dx=\frac{dy}{nkx^{n-1}}$. The bounds are still $0$ and $+\infty$